# Should I blacklist countries to stop brute force attacks?

Tags: brute-force, wordpress, blacklist

I'm getting attacks at wp-admin from numerous countries and IPs. When I get a notification from Wordfence that there has been an attack, I blacklist the originating country from the WP backend. Then I get more attacks from other countries. Should I keep blacklisting countries, or try another method?

(Already in place: good password, not an obvious login name, 3 failures, 3 failed forgotten passwords, 4-hour lockout.)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Who should be able to log in to your site? Only you, others, from what countries? If it's just you or one country, you can just block all the rest.

Comment: Reed: I followed your reminder to block every country besides the U.S. Since doing so, I'm not getting any warnings that foreign-based hackers are trying to get into my site. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you did is enough. If someone from another country really wants to bruteforce your credentials, he can use a proxy / vpn but will still be blocked by your security mechanisms. Blacklisting other countries could be interesting only if a non human tries the bruteforce automatically.

Comment: It probably doesn't matter, but I'm wondering if it's one person who is somehow spoofing IP addresses traceable to many countries. There is a pattern to the usernames that the attacker(s) is/are trying.